# Calculating the Molarity of an Ion?

Tags: aqueous-solution, experimental-chemistry, ions

I'm completely stuck on this one - I was doing an experiment in a lab and now I cannot find the molarity of an ion in a solution. I've looked everywhere on the web but after 2 hours of searching I couldn't find anything. Maybe I am looking in the wrong direction.

I mixed three solutions: 1mL of $\ce{0.1M ~CuSO4}$,  $\ce{0.28 M ~~NH3}$ and  water.
This solution turned into

$$\ce{Cu(H2O)4^{2+} + 4NH3 = Cu(NH3)4^{2+} + 4H2O}$$

This turned the solution from light blue to dark blue-ish purple. The final mL of the mixed solutions was 25 mL.
Now I am supposed to calculate the molarity of the $\ce{Cu(NH3)4^{2+}}$ ion. I am pretty sure that I only have to calculate the molarity of $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ but I am not entirely sure. If you guys could give me some help on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: you need to know more information like the volume of the 0.1M solution and the volume of the final mixed solution to calculate the molarity of Cu(NH3)4^(2+)

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! If you had any questions about the policies of our community, you can ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help) or take a ‎‎[tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) of the website.‎ You can visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation "LaTex at ‎chemistry.SE") to find out how to make your future posts better.‎

Comment: I'm sorry! I did forget to add the volume - I will add it right now.

Comment: Is the 1 ml also for the ammonia solution?